# ServiceStack Redis what is urn

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

What does "urn:" stand for?

I am playing with the ServiceStack Redis example. It seems like a naming convention, many keys in the db starting with "urn:".

By calling `somePoco.CreateUrn();` --> `"urn:somePoco:123"` It creates the key in the database.

And the advantage of it is that RedisTypedClient can regonize it in the following code:
e.g.

```
var redisSomePoco = redis.As<SomePoco>();
var somePoco = redisSomePoco.GetById("123"); //it knows I want value of key "urn:somePoco:123"
redisSomePoco.Store(somePoco); //it knows how to store my poco value in key "urn:somePoco:123"
//"{\"Id\":123,\"DisplayName\":\"Michael\"}"
```

Is my understanding correct? Or am I even close?

Comment: For the general term (regardless of Redis usage): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is it because with the standard "urn:" prefix the RedisTypedClient can regonize its poco object type? My understanding is correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It stands for [Uniform Resource Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name).

Since there is no concept of namespaces or schemas in Redis we use a fully-qualified key with the format of:

```
urn:{TypeName}:{Id}
```

To uniquely store and identify any POCO instance stored in Redis using the **Typed API** of [ServiceStack's C# RedisClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis).

The [RedisAdmin UI](http://www.servicestack.net/RedisAdminUI/AjaxClient/) also takes advantage of this convention to provide a hierarchical *tree-like structure* to access your data despite their being no concept of such in Redis.

Comment: Hi mythz. I also looked at the RedisAdmin UI installed in my localhost and took a guess from there. Thanks for helping me understanding the structure :)

Comment: would be great to have more control over this name. for example if you want to store the same object for different purposes, then i customize the Namespaceprefix, but the url looks a little bit weard: urn:mypurpose:urn:{TypeName}:{Id} (i have the urn twice). or is there an easier way?